# Multiple calls to SetBinding from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multibinding

I have multiple C# objects that need to be notified when a property changes (the property belongs to a FrameworkElement, like a button or a listbox).

I humbly tested binding a single object using the SetBinding method like this:

```
// DepOb is my FrameworkElement
// DepPropDesc is the DependencyPropertyDescriptor

System.Windows.Data.Binding bind = new System.Windows.Data.Binding();
bind.Source = this;
bind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
bind.Mode = ob.BindingMode;
DepOb.SetBinding(DepPropDesc.DependencyProperty, bind);
```

But when I create a second object and bind it, the first one is no longer called.  If I read between the lines, the method sets *the* binding, so the previous one is flushed, right?

MSDN talks about a "multibinding" object, but I don't know how to "get" previous bindings stored in multibinding so that I may append new bindings to it.

I will continue searching but I wanted to see if anyone here had ideas about what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Seb

Answer (score 2):

Bindings are set on the second object you want to bind to the first object. When you set a binding on the second object the value that may have been set on the second object is lost and the value to the first object is available for reading and writing (when set to TwoWay).

```
grid2.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = grid1 });
```

there for is you had a grid3 you could then also do:

```
grid3.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = grid1 });
```

In this example WidthProperty is the static readonly property defined on the FrameworkElement grid2 and grid3 inherit from FrameworkElement so they can use this property.

In your code you need to write something like this (noting BindingMode.OneWay on the mode).

```
System.Windows.Data.Binding bind = new System.Windows.Data.Binding();       
bind.Source = this;       
bind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;       
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");       
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
DepOb.SetBinding(DepObClass.WidthOrSomethingProperty, bind);
```

Because you are binding to an instance (DepOb) you need to define the actual property (or use an inherited one) on it's class definition like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthOrSomethingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WidthOrSomething", typeof(double), typeof(DepObClass), null);
```

In the implementation of DepObClass you should define your property like:

```
public double WidthOrSomething
{
     get { return GetValue(WidthOrSomethingProperty); }
     set { SetValue(WidthOrSomethingProperty, value); }
 }
```

Hope that helps.